# Python2.7 OpenCV 2.4.13 SIFT OutOfMemoryError

Tags: python-2.7, opencv, sift, autorotate

Really appreciate your kind support in helping me with the problem I had been facing recently.
**Objective:** To auto-rotate the image to the original form, for eg- in a scanned copy of an Identity Card and the ID is rotated by certain angle, I'm trying to extract the features of the rotated image to get the natural shape.

**Methodology:** I was trying to implement Scale-Invariant Feature Transform (SIFT) on python for the above problem but unfortunately it is failing due to OutOfMemoryError.
Full Error:
error: ........\opencv\modules\core\src\alloc.cpp:52: error: (-4) Failed to allocate 139365828 bytes in function cv::OutOfMemoryError

[Image used for the test case](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nDxVA.jpg)

If someone could help me out on the above error or any other solution to the problem is really appreciated.

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. Without code, it's not possible to find the error

Comment: import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread('input_img.png')
gray= cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
sift = cv2.SIFT()
kp = sift.detect(gray,None)
img=cv2.drawKeypoints(gray,kp)
cv2.imwrite('sift_keypoints.png',img)